# Python "make_transforms" shows list index error while aligning fits images

Tags: python, fits

I am trying to align 4 fits (V2.fits,V3.fits,V4.fits and, V5.fits) with respect to a reference fits file (V1.fits). I tried the following by employing the python fits_align package :

```
from fits_align.ident import make_transforms
from fits_align.align import affineremap
from glob import glob
from astropy.io import fits
from numpy import shape
import os

img_list = sorted(glob(os.path.join("*.fits")))
ref_image = img_list[0]
images_to_align = img_list[1:]

print(img_list) # List of all images
print(ref_image) # Reference image
print(images_to_align) # Images to align

identifications = make_transforms(ref_image, images_to_align)
aligned_images = [ref_image]

    for id in identifications:
    
     if id.ok:
        alignedimg = affineremap(id.ukn.filepath, id.trans, outdir=tmpdir)
        aligned_images.append(alignedimg)
```

I get the following index error:

[image]

What could be the reasons for this error? please suggest possible solutions

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors or other text. Just copy the original text into your question.

Comment: @James Sorry for the mistake. I shall take care of such mistakes in my posts now onwards.